# Is V's lair based in a real place?

Tags: real-location, vertigo-comics, v-for-vendetta

When Evey wakes up in V's home, he tells her she has to stay with him because otherwise she could give away the location of his lair. She counters that she has no idea where they are, and he says the following:

> You know it's underground. You know the color of the stone. That would be enough for a clever man.

This has always bothered me because it seems to be so insanely untrue. Those two facts couldn't possibly be enough to locate something. Could they?

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but why would he call her a clever man?

Comment: He lives in Victoria understand station doesn't he? I don't have the book to hand to check, but I'm sure I remember this to be the case.

Comment: “Those two facts couldn't possibly be enough to locate something. Could they?” Sherlock Holmes would probably get it. With enough knowledge of London’s geology, it might be enough.

Comment: @JohnRennie Yep...turns out that is indeed the case.

Comment: I feel like the question in the subject and the question in the body don't actually have the same answer. Is there a canon answer to the question in the body? (Are two facts enough to locate it?)

Comment: How are the questions different?

Comment: @MrLister - Is he talking about the man she might report him to?

Comment: "Those two facts couldn't possibly be enough to locate something." - That depends on how distinct those two features are - maybe stone of that particular colour is well-known to be used in Victoria station.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### V's secret hideout is an abandoned Victoria Station.

This is confirmed in the film canon by the [shooting script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/V-for-Vendetta.html) (referring to the location as "**Interior : Victoria Station"**) as well as the quote;

> **V :** *This is the old Victoria line but it is blocked, blocked
> somewhere between Whitehall and St. James.*

and

> Suddenly, Finch stops. Carefully, as if reaching to touch a butterfly,
> he slips a single sheet out from the sheaves covering his desk.
> The paper has a long list: the names of all the Queens of England. He has circled in red the **V in Victoria.**
> When it hits him, it hits him like a falling safe.
>
> **FINCH** : *Christ!  That's it!  It's got to be it!*

and

> The shadow is cast by a sign for **Victoria Station**, part of the
> abandoned subway.

And the film's [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5812.V_for_Vendetta)

> And only two London tube stations started with V: Victoria and
> Vauxhall, and the latter was south of the river, away from the centers
> of power... away from all the scenes of Vs exploits. If it was
> anywhere, it had to be Victoria...
>
> Not far away, the target of Finch's search was dancing slowly with a
> beautiful woman in his arms.

Within the Alan Moore/David Lloyd comic-books we also see that the final scene is indeed set inside an abandoned Victoria Station.

[image]

Comment: Alan Moore didn't draw the comic, that was David Lloyd.

Comment: Oops. The perils of trying to quote multiple sources.

Comment: Ah StackExchange....where all knowledge winds up sooner or later.

Comment: @Aerovistae - If something's worth quoting, it's worth quoting from eight different canon sources ;-)

Comment: Just noticed that the falling `THIS STATION CLOSED` sign combines with what's visible of the `I` in Victoria to form a `Y` -- `VICTORY`. Wonder if that's deliberate.